# I can't switch between animations

Tags: animation

I have 2 animations inside the same blend file, they appear as different animations in the action editor and the timelines change when I choose between the two in the drop down menu, but the actual animation does not change; I'm stuck on my run animation and I would like to be able to switch to my idle animation

My blend file:

https://www58.zippyshare.com/v/jkvFtxvV/file.html

Comment: Are you using the NLA (Non-linear-Animation) Editor? Like here: https://youtu.be/vpyG0_AizD0?t=183

Comment: zippyshare has geoblocking in some countrys unfortunately. Uploading it here is mor accesible: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: A M it doesn't quite look like that, I'm in the plain animation window where I have the action editor selected from the drop down

Comment: then you should check it out. Its its own editor type, you find it in the second collum "Nonlinear Animation". Using the video link you should be able to manage your actions, if they are setup correctly. cant look at the file, dont have a vpn at hand and have geoblocking with zippy unfortunately. For cleaning your actions up Simon Broggi's answer seems promissing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the armature and then change the action in the action editor. You created the animation for the armature, then applied it to the mesh object in the action editor by mistake. This doesn't do anything because the animation expects the transform hierarchy of the armature. You can check in the outliner where your animations are. They should only exist under the armature, not under the mesh objects.

- Select Cube and remove the action in the action editor.
- Select Cube.001 and remove the
  action in the action editor.
- Select Armature and choose the action you want to play and it
  should work.

Comment: Your idle animation is called ArmatureAction, and your run animation is called ArmatureAction.001.  The animations Idle, Run and ArmatureAction.002 don't seem to hold any data.

Comment: Oh, and while you're tidying up, also remove the animation called ArmatureAction from the Camera! :-)